# What is the effect of lambda on ARIMA?

Tags: r, lambda, arima

Lambda made different effects on the same series.
- What can we say about this?
- What kind of effect does Lambda have?
- Should I prefer Lambda like this example?
Or should I not?
- Is it enough for me to look at RMSE for this?
- Yes, lambda normalizes the data. But when should I choose?
There have been many questions. I'm sorry, but I'm very confused. I am trying to build a model with ARIMA on the data below. What can be said about the results of the model?

> [image: Blockquote]

```
>ARIMA_e <- forecast(auto.arima(train_e, lambda=0), h=h_e)
>accuracy(ARIMA_e)
                    ME     RMSE      MAE         MPE     MAPE      MASE       ACF1
Training set 0.3842223 11.42344 8.968908 -0.04237153 2.835176 0.6816815 -0.1057754

>ARIMA_e <- forecast(auto.arima(train_e), h=h_e)
>accuracy(ARIMA_e)
                      ME     RMSE      MAE        MPE     MAPE      MASE        ACF1
Training set 0.009080438 11.72061 9.258278 -0.2989164 2.951468 0.7036751 -0.02705381
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda defines a Box-Cox transformation, as defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform.

In particular, setting it to zero corresponds to first taking the `log` of the values, forecasting the resulting time series, and then taking the inverse operation on the forecasts (i.e. `exp`). This can be useful if you expect your resulting time series to be positive, since after taking the `exp`, no negative values can occur.

See also https://otexts.com/fpp3/transformations.html for more examples.